# Problema al obtener un Json desde conexión Http Android 4.4 y 5

Tags: android, json, http

Buen día, me encuentro tratando de resolver el siguiente problema:

Mediante el siguiente código ejecuto una URL y obtengo un
JsonArray

```
public class ClaseListar {
    private JSONArray json;

    public JSONArray mtdListar(String url, Context context) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy Policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(Policy);


        HttpClient objCliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext objContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet objGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse objResponse = objCliente.execute(objGet, objContext);
            HttpEntity objEntidad = objResponse.getEntity();
            String resultado = EntityUtils.toString(objEntidad, "UTF-8");
            json= new JSONArray(resultado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

El código funciona perfectamente en Android 6 Y 7 pero en Android 4.4 y 5 no funciona, ¿que estoy haciendo mal?, ya he investigado en internet y no hay mucha información sobre este problema.

Para los objetos de conexión estoy usando unas librerías de Apache que encontré en la red.
De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

tuve un problema muy similar al tuyo, al parecer es porque en android 4 y 5 no tienes instaladados los certificados ssl de google. en mi caso lo resolvi llamando a la siguiente linea de código:

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
```

En mi caso yo lo puse en mi clase Aplicaction de esta forma:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>(){

            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                try {
                    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    return e;

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    return e;
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception e) {
                super.onPostExecute(e);

                if(e instanceof GooglePlayServicesRepairableException){
                    // Indicates that Google Play services is out of date, disabled, etc.

                    // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                            ((GooglePlayServicesRepairableException)e).getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if(e instanceof GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException){
                    // Indicates a non-recoverable error; the ProviderInstaller is not able
                    // to install an up-to-date Provider.
                }
            }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

Tambien puede funcionar si lo inicializas desde tu SplashActivity, es decir antes que llames a algun servicio. Saludos